# How to catch the error message from Chem.MolFromSmiles('Formula')

Tags: python, rdkit

I'm new to this rdkit, below is the code that I'm using to get the chemical image from the formula,

```
from rdkit import Chem
m = Chem.MolFromSmiles('OCC1OC(C(C(C1O)O)O)[C]1(C)(CO)CC(=O)C=C(C1CCC(=O)C)C')
m
```

if the code is correct, it displays the structre. The above code displays the error saying

```
"[15:23:55] Explicit valence for atom # 11 C, 5, is greater than permitted"
```

I tried adding try catch but, it does not help.

I need to catch this exception/Message and display it to the user.

How can we do this?[Issue Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Th3AL.png)

```
try:
   from rdkit import Chem
   m = Chem.MolFromSmiles('OCC1OC(C(C(C1O)O)O)[C]1(C)(CO)CC(=O)C=C(C1CCC(=O)C)C')
   m
except Exception as e:
   print(e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not an Error, it is a Warning. Your code does not break doing that assignment. So there is no Error to catch.

**But** your solution lays within the return of `Chem.MolFromSmiles`. If it fails to build a mol object of your SMILES it returns `None`, whereas it returns the mol object when it manages to "deal with the SMILES properly".

For sure you can raise an error yourself!

```py
from rdkit import Chem

m = Chem.MolFromSmiles('OCC1OC(C(C(C1O)O)O)[C]1(C)(CO)CC(=O)C=C(C1CCC(=O)C)C')

if m is None:
    print("hey user, there was an error!")

# or even raise an error:
if m is None:
    raise ValueError("Could not interpret SMILES to mol object")
```

I know my answer is lacking. My solution is not forwarding the warning to the user. I feel like it is quite hard to do. If there is a solution it might be found utilizing `logging` or `warnings` package. I would also be interested in that but couldn't manage so far myself.